# XNA Game in ASP.Net web site

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, xna

I was wondering, though I have got quite a few articles in this regard and all of them are for previous versions of XNA or not what I need, is it possible to embed an xna game in a asp.net website???
Means like there are several websites (game portals) having several games of may b flash or java. But is it possible to embed your xna game in a web site, and play it on web. May be using Silverlight so that User playing online do not have to updates its DirectX drivers or stuff.
I am a beginner in Game Development.
Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately Silverlight and XNA are two very different things. XNA is for creating games that will be playable on PC, Xbox and soon Windows Phone 7 devices with very complex graphics and visual effects.

Silverlight is a bit like flash, offers a possibility to create an application that will run in a website environment. It's still possible to make games in Silverlight, but you won't be able to use all the things offered by XNA in graphics.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [silvesprite](http://silversprite.codeplex.com/)  As Gimly stated you must transform it to silverlight, this is actually possible (not overly difficult) you will lose some features, but it is possible.